# A finite cancellative monoid is a group? Need help seeing why the following is a false proof.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, semigroups

I proved this in the following way is our exam, but got $0$ out of $7$ points for it, however I fail to see why its wrong:

> Let $a\in S$ be arbitrary. Since $S$ is finite, there has to be some $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a^m=e$, otherwise all the powers of $a$ would be different. Then $a^m = a^m(a^{-1}a)$, and by cancellation we get $e = a^{-1}a$, so that $a^{-1}$ is the left inverse.

Similarly I showed a right inverse exists, hence a unique two sided inverse exists, so $S$ is a group. Being periodic, I know some power of $a$ has to be an idempotent, so that power becomes the identity.

Comment: It looks more or less right. Finiteness gives that $a^m=a^{m+n}$ for some $m,n$. But $a^{m+n}=a^ma^n$, so we can cancel to get $a^n=1$. If $n=1$ we have $a=1$. For $n>1$ we have $a^{n-1}a=a^n=aa^{n-1}$, so $a^{n-1}$ is a two-sided inverse for $a$. If $b$ is another inverse, then we have $ab=aa^{n-1}$, so cancellation gives us $b=a^{n-1}$.

Comment: I find $0/7$ a little harsh! As James Mitchell says, the main problem is that you wrote $a^{-1}$ while trying to prove that $a^{-1}$ exists, which was probably regarded as a fatal mistake. But I would give it about $2/7$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that $e$ is the identity of your monoid. Why does there have to be a power of $a$ equal to the identity? As the commenter above says there have to be two powers of $a$ that are equal but not necessarily equal to the identity, at least without first proving you the monoid is a group. Also when you write $a^m = a^m aa ^{-1}$ what is $a ^ {-1}$? You'd maybe like to say the inverse of $a$, but we don't know that there is one yet. You seem to be using the fact that your monoid is a group to prove that it is a group. You see the problem with that, right?

Comment: I see your points. Can this method be made to reach the right conclusion in another way still?

Comment: @almagest already wrote a correct solution in his comment, it is somewhat similar to your solution.

Comment: It seems more like I might not have used the 'correct' notation, otherwise, what is the difference between writing $a^{m-1} a$ and $a^{m} a^{-1} a$?

Comment: @conner. There is a critical difference. $a^{m-1}$ means $a\cdot a\cdot a\dots\cdot a$ (with $m-1$ $a$s). Whereas $a^{-1}$ means the inverse of $a$ whose existence you are trying to establish.

Comment: @almagest is correct, that's precisely the issue

Comment: @almagest You're right, and of course I know that. I'm just kicking myself about getting this proof wrong, hence the comment above, trying to convince you to say with me that I deserved some partial credit.